# Images not loading in IE11

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-11

I have a remote url for an image which I have to display. Below is the snippet of code.

```
var tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.onload = function() {
  console.log('image loaded');
};
tempImage.src = url;
```

This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. But in IE11, `onload` event is not getting triggered.

In chrome's network tab I have seen image starts downloading once finished it triggers the `onload` event. But for IE11, In network tab, I found the image is not getting downloaded completely, which seems to be the reason because of which neither image is getting displayed nor `onload` is getting triggered.

[image]

Is there any way to handle this situation. Any hints will be really appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
Post adding new keyword before function, onload is getting triggered but image is getting displayed as cross.

[image]

Comment: What type of image is it?

Comment: @Teemu it will be either png or jpg.

Comment: Is the image present at the source ? Do you see image is requested in Network tab in IE 11? Are you waiting for the image to be completely loaded ? Your code worked for me without any change.

Comment: The "new trick" feels a bit hackish ... Attach an onerror event to the image, it'll fire if the loading fails. Though it won't fix the actual issue at hands.

Comment: Image is present and it is requested in network tab. In the response i am getting corrupted image, screenshot is attached. @AdityaBhave

Comment: @Teemu already tried, but its not getting triggered as the service is giving 200 status.

Comment: Do you have a page (or image) address we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have but it wont work without session..

Comment: If you'll upload the image to another host, like imgur or sth, can you load it from there to IE? Are just some, or all the images corrupted, when you trying to load them to IE?

Comment: "https://i.ibb.co/2S6pTmX/190k86-O-Imgur.png"  i have tried with this image, it worked fine.. but not getting whats wrong with my host server. though its working fine on other browsers.

Comment: This can be caused by a compatibility problem between Internet Explorer and the site you're on. you could check the IE browser Compatibility View, more detail information, please check [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/internet-explorer-11-not-displaying-picture-images/b947e0fe-e726-4f9f-bbd6-4857be94ff60).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT tried both the method, but no luck.. :(

Comment: Another method, you could try to [resetting the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and check whether it works or not. If still not working. I have tried to use your code with this url (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlMQ7.jpg), it works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0 version), so, as a workaround, you could try to upload your image to the imgur site.

Comment: Yes its working fine for me as well.. but when i am pointing to my server i am getting issue of corrupted image.. server code also seems fine as its working on other browsers..

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in IE11.

```
var tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.onload = new function() {
  console.log('image loaded');
};
tempImage.src = url;
```

The above code should solve your problem. Note that the only difference is addition of the key word "new" before "function" on line 2.

Comment: Actually, I have never met issues with IE and onload event of an image ... and definitely have not needed `new` to get it work. Can you provide a link to an explanation of this "known problem"?

Comment: onload getting triggered post addition of new keyword, but instead of image its coming as a cross.